# Using jsPlumb with highmaps

Tags: highcharts, jsplumb, highmaps

I am using Highmaps and I have a map of the world with map markers all over. I want to show connection between map markers so I decided to use jsPlumb. I set an id to the highcharts data as so:

```
data: [{
      id: "MT",
      x: 907.49, 
      y: -1485.43
  }
],
```

I tried to get the id defined here using javascript and it worked. jsPlumb requires id of an element both for the source and target, as so:

```
jsPlumb.connect({
   source: 'MT',
   target: 'GPin1',
   anchors: [['Right'], ['Left']],
   endpoint: ["Dot", {
   radius: 0.1
}],
```

The problem is that jsPlumb does not recognize the id defined in highcharts and returns an error on console. How can I settle this any ideas please?

Comment: Is jsPlumb using DOM id's? Because Highcharts point's id is only inner id, not available outside the chart's instance.

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?